# Qt splitter auto resizing

Tags: c++, qt

I have a 4 way splitter in qt, i want to be able to expand the splitter when a user moves one of the tabs instead of collapsing the other tabs to make room.

This is the default state of the splitter when the program launches:[image]

This is the state of the splitter after I try to expand the left most tab of the splitter.[image]

See how in the second picture the splitter has just smushed the three tabs on the right together to make room for the tab I expanded? Instead of this happening i would like the entire splitter to grow to preserve the size of the 3 tabs on the right and to accommodate the expanding left tab.

One last thing, this splitter is nested inside a scrollarea to accommodate the expanding splitter widget.

Does anyone know how I would go about accomplishing this?

One idea that I had was to keep track of the sizes of the individual tabs before and after the user resizes a splitter and then adjust the size of the entire splitter to reflect the increase or decrease in the adjusted tab and reset the other tabs to what they were prior to the change. However I am not sure how to get the sizes of all of the tabs before and after a resize.